# Responsive Design vs Native Mobile Native APP?

Tags: web-applications, responsive-design, mobile-application

This question is whether its really worth to go for native apps when i already have responsive web apps. As if i go for native apps, i need to develop it per platform
i.e. ios/andoid/windows which means more money/time whereas in case of responsive web design i need to stick to single development
process which will work on all browsers

**Note :-**
 Here i mean those apps which are dynamic i.e. requires interaction with server. For staic app , sure winner is native apps
as they don't require internet connection and can work offline

**Accessibility and Brand Marketing :-** On this parameter native app is bigger winner .As in case of webapp, i need to think of brand, open browser, click the domain name
and login while in native app its single click from  mobile home page. For less sensitive site, it may remember login info and hence can get rid of login process

But for rest of the parameters, i find both Responsive Design  and Native Mobile APP  almost same. Yes UI/UX may be designed better for apps but it requires more investment too

Can experts any other major advantage of mobile native app over Responsive Design ?

Source :- http://thinkapps.com/blog/development/responsive-web-vs-native-apps/

Comment: You can write mobile hybrid apps f.e: on Ionic Framework http://ionicframework.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a major difference when you go comparing performances of both `Native Apps` and `Responsive Web`.
Native apps needs to interact to server only for data transactions. While, Responsive web design loads whole of your content including JavaScript, CSS, Images and other web content from server, then it renders inside it within an Android WebView or Browser (Whatever you may be using).

Yes, It's worth it to develop native apps. Moreover, it depends on your development requirement.

Answer (score 1):

With Progressive Web App (PWA), issue of reloading static files every time is solved with Service worker- chache. PWA also gives various native app like options, including hardware access(not all hardware available as of Mar-2018), but still good enough for most apps out there. Cordova fills the other hardware access gap, when used, still taking advantage of PWA.

Here is a detailed look on PWA. -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/49366789/1057093